# How to fit an ARMAX model with more than one exogenous time series?

Tags: time-series

I am trying to fit an ARMAX with two exogenous time series with the following code but it gives me an "computationally singular" error. I know it is about defining more than 2 time series for `xreg` because when I include only one exogenous it works!
This is link for [data](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4041955/DATA.csv)

```
library(forecast)

data<-read.csv("DATA.csv")

Y1=ts(data[,1], start=1978, frequency=12)

#exogenous time series
Y2<-matrix(0,360,2)
Y2[,1]<-cbind(data[,2])
Y2[,2]<-cbind(data[,3])

model<- arima (Y1, order=c(1, 0, 0), xreg=as.ts(Y2, start=1978, frequency=12))

predict (model, 10, newxreg=0)
```

I get this Error:

```
 in solve.default(res$hessian * n.used, A) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 5.67866e-34
```

Comment: What do the values of `data[,2]` and `data[,3]` look like? Do the values of either `data[,2]` or `data[,3]` tend to be close to zero? Are the values of `data[,2] - data[,3]` close to zero?

Comment: @BlueMarker Thank you for your comment I looked at my data again and I found out problem was there and now it is solved I will remove the question shortly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a perfect correlation between the regressors, `Y[,1]` is $2.5$ times `Y[,2]`.

```
all.equal(Y2[,1], Y2[,2] * 2.5)
# [1] TRUE
cor(Y2[,1], Y2[,2])
#[1] 1
```

This makes the Hessian matrix non-invertible. The same problem will arise in a linear regression since the crossproduct of the matrix of regressors `Y2'Y2` 
is not invertbible and hence the Ordinary Least Square estimator cannot be computed.

```
det(crossprod(Y2))
# [1] -5.464545e-12
solve(crossprod(Y2))
# Error in solve.default(crossprod(Y2)) : 
#   system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 2.30218e-17
```

One of the regressors does not contribute new information so you can stick to include only one of the regressors.